# Creating a named vector from a dataset in R

Tags: r, vector, shiny, dplyr, waffle-chart

I have a dataset simplified as follows:

```
print(data)
Team   Colour
A      Red
B      Red
C      Blue
D      Green
```

I want to produce a waffle chart (square pie chart) of this data. I can do this very easily through:

```
waffle(c(Red = sum(data$Colour == "Red"), 
         Blue = sum(data$Colour = "Blue"), 
         Green = sum(data$colour = "Green")))
```

However, I cannot seem to find an easy way to produce the named integer created within the waffle function above, through manipulation of my dataset. I need it to be produced directly from the original dataset as I will need it to be a reactive function within a shiny app.

I have tried using `group_by` within dplyr:

```
forwaffle <- data%>%
             group_by(Colour)
             summarise(frequency=n())
```

However, I cannot convert this list into the required named integer. I have tried using `t()` and `unlist()` but neither of these achieve my desired result.

Comment: Please can you edit your waffle code example so as it works. There are missing "=" and mixed upper/lower case Colour/colour. It's hard to know what the desired result should be. Also your second example is missing a pipe.

Comment: `waffle(table(data$Colour))`?

Answer (score 0):

If by "required named integer" you mean that the colours should be column names, then you can use `tidyr::spread`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  group_by(Colour) %>% 
  summarise(frequency = n()) %>% 
  spread(Colour, frequency)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
   Blue Green   Red
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

A shorter `tidyverse` solution using `deframe` (thanks to @r2evans):

```
count(df, Colour) %>%
    tibble::deframe() %>%
    waffle(.)
```

---

The solution by @r2evans in the comment above is definitely the most concise but if you insist on using a `tidyverse` approach you can do:

```
setNames(
    df %>% count(Colour) %>% pull(n),
    df %>% count(Colour) %>% pull(Colour)) %>%
waffle(.)
```

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Team   Colour
A      Red
B      Red
C      Blue
D      Green", header = T)
```

Comment: Alternatives: `count(df, Colour) %>% tibble::deframe()` or `... %>% with(., setNames(n, Colour))`.

Comment: Aah, `deframe` was what I was looking for!! Thanks @r2evans. I hope you don't mind if I add this to the solution.

Comment: Feel free! I much prefer calculating things only once, the double-pipe method was making me twitch ;-)

Comment: @r2evans Yes the double-pipe is awful;-) was trying to avoid but went down the wrong path trying (and failing) to use `purrr:map`...

Comment: Right, `map` would have done alright too. It might have been best to save the `count` results and work off them, but then again SO can be a "hasty solutions" site, not always worth the effort to put in more than the gist.